# Target and animate an element

Tags: javascript

I got an input inside the label `#container`, and I wanna animate an element `#item` with some CSS like transform and keyframes.

For some reason, the input has to be in the div `#fixed`. Otherwise, I know I can just remove the label from the div and use:

`#container > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ item` to target the element and apply the animation with CSS only.

How do I target the element `#item` by Javascript and apply the CSS animation `move` if the input is checked?

```css
#container > input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

#selection {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(-600px);
  animation: move 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-600px);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

#container > input[type=checkbox]:checked + #selection {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
  <label id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p id="selection">animate</p>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is an example. I added one more option, so that you can check both item 1 and 2. You can see that the eventlistener is pointing to the form and by using the name attribute on the input element I can select the item with the right id.

Input elements can also be unchecked again.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.forms.fixed.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let id = e.target.name;
    let elm = document.getElementById(id);
    elm.classList.remove('movein', 'moveout');
    if(e.target.checked){
      elm.classList.add('movein');
    }else{
      elm.classList.add('moveout');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
form[name="fixed"] input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.selection {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(-600px);
}

.movein {
  animation: movein 1.5s forwards;
}

.moveout {
  animation: moveout 1.5s normal;
}

@keyframes movein {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-600px);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes moveout {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(-600px);
    }
}

form[name="fixed"] input[type=checkbox]:checked + .selection {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form name="fixed">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item01" />
    <p class="selection">animate 01</p>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item02" />
    <p class="selection">animate 02</p>
  </label>
</form>

<div id="item01" class="item">Item 01</div>
<div id="item02" class="item">Item 02</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelector` to select the input, and attach a `change` event Listener to it. Then, using `.checked`, you can add the animation to `#item`.

```js
let inpt = document.querySelector("input");

inpt.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  if(inpt.checked){
    document.querySelector("#item").style.animation = "move 1.5s forwards";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#item").style.animation = "moveBack 1.5s forwards";
  }
})
```

```css
#container > input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

#selection {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(-600px);
}

@keyframes move {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-600px);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes moveBack {
    to {
        transform: translateX(-600px);
    }
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
#container > input[type=checkbox]:checked + #selection {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixed">
  <label id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <p id="selection">animate</p>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="item"></div>
```

Comment: @NojusPiper Just FYI, I have added code for moving the box behind, when checkbox isn't checked.